# dock video appear when scoll and disappear when next article is in the viewport

Tags: ajax, video, dock

how can I specify what element dock video will show only and disappear when next video article is loaded?

I specify what element dock video will show only and disappear when next video article is loaded

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.